# error rsqlite_fetch in R

Tags: r, rsqlite

I have a "CSV" format dataset with 28 variables and 7400 observation. I import the dataset in R with the name of "films" and I want to clean that. In this way, I use "sqldf" and "SQLite" libraries. But when I use "sqldf" I receive the warnings and consequently my dataset does not update too:

[image]

```
color   director_name   num_critic_for_reviews  duration
Color   James Cameron   723                       178
Color   Gore Verbinski  302                       169
Color   Sam Mendes      602                       148
```

the code I have used is as below:

```
library(RSQLite) 
library(sqldf)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "tempdb")  

dbWriteTable(db,"films",films, overwrite=TRUE)

d <- sqldf(c('update films set movie_title=lower(movie_title)', 'select * from films'))
d <- sqldf(c('update films set actor_3_name=lower(actor_3_name)', 'select * from films'))
d <- sqldf(c('update films set actor_2_name=lower(actor_2_name)', 'select * from films'))
d <- sqldf(c('update films set actor_1_name=lower(actor_1_name)', 'select * from films'))
d <- sqldf(c('update films set director_name=lower(director_name)', 'select * from films'))


# Warning message:
# In rsqlite_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
#   Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries
```

What is the problem?

Comment: One problem: you are mistaking a `warning` for an `error`. Another problem: `dbGetQuery` assumes there is data to return, but you are just updating; consider `dbExecute` (or `dbSendQuery` and `dbClearResult`) instead.

Comment: Thank you. I used dbExecute but it just creates a "d" value that shows the number of "colors" and my dataset (film) does not update.

Comment: Are you saying you expect your update to the db table to be reflected in the `films` variable in R?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I want to change all `colors` change to `color` in my dataset `films`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems at work here.

**First**:

```
# Warning message:
# In rsqlite_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
#   Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries
```

This is a warning, not an error. In fact, it appears to be somewhat new issue in `RSQLite`, and is referenced in an open issue: https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/issues/227.

(For cleanness, I'm removing it from the output in the rest of this answer, though it occurs with each non-`select` query.)

**Second**, `RSQLite` deals with a database, period. It has no opinion or awareness of variables within the R environment, so there is no suggestion that a variable in R is an immediate and perpetual representation of a database table. (There are similar methodologies using [`dbplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/index.html) that *do* do this, roughly speaking.)

In order to provide this type of tie between R and some form of SQL querying, there's `sqldf` that allows you to query against R variables as if they were actual SQL tables. When you do such a query, it grabs the data.frame as it currently looks, inserts it into a temporary database table (whether `RSQLite` or another), runs the SQL code, then returns what you need.

**Third**: despite this apparent tie, it is quite functional in that it does not produce [side-effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/40314/147602) within the R environment. That means that if you want to store the resulting data in a way that R can use, you need to explicitly capture the new table into an R variable.

For example:

```
library(sqldf)
(mt <- mtcars[1:5,1:5])
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15
```

After the update, the original data is untouched.

```
sqldf('update mt set cyl=5 where cyl>5')
mt
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15
```

You can get the data individually or in the same line by including a `select * from ...` in your call to `sqldf`:

```
mt2 <- sqldf(c('update mt set cyl=5 where cyl>5', 'select * from mt'))
mt2
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# 1 21.0   5  160 110 3.90
# 2 21.0   5  160 110 3.90
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85
# 4 21.4   5  258 110 3.08
# 5 18.7   5  360 175 3.15
```

(In this case I saved it to `mt2`, but you could just have easily over-written it.)

All of this is discussed in various forms in the [`sqldf` FAQ 8](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf), "8. Why am I having problems with update?"

## EDIT

There appear to be several misunderstandings about `sqldf` and such.

1. You are creating a `db` handle for direct SQL queries (not `sqldf`), but you never use it. As you'll see later, either (a) use `dbExecute` (and related functions) with the `db` handle, or (b) use `sqldf`, no need for `dbConnect` and friends.
2. When using `sqldf`, on *each and every* call to `sqldf` it does a *complete copy* of the current instance of the variable into a database. (This is both helpful and, at times, inefficient. With smaller datasets, the time lost is likely not felt, but still ...) So when you keep referring to the *table* `films`, it is ignoring the `d` you created, because it has no way to infer what you are trying to do outside of its call ... it just copies, queries, and discards.

   ```
   # assuming this is something like what you do ... but it doesn't matter
   films <- read.csv("films.csv", ...)
   #    `-<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<-+-<--.
   db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "tempdb") # not used in sqldf          ^     \
   dbWriteTable(db, "films", films, overwrite=TRUE) # never used    ^      \
   #                             `--- is referring to --->--->--->--'       \
   d <- sqldf(c('update films set movie_title=lower(movie_title)', #         \
                                'select * from films')) #                     \
   #                        \                      `--- (internal to sqldf)    ^
   #                         `--- refers to the original 'films' --->--->--->--'
   ```

   **Option 1**, use the `RSQLite` functions, not `sqldf`:

   ```
   db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "tempdb")
   dbWriteTable(db,"films",films, overwrite=TRUE)
   dbExecute(db, 'update films set actor_3_name=lower(actor_3_name)')
   #        `--- repeat for all updates
   films <- dbGetQuery(db, 'select * from films')
   ```

   **Option 2**, (not my preferred) use the variable created on the previous line:

   ```
   films <- read.csv("films.csv", ...)
   #   `--<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<-.
   d <- sqldf(c('update films set movie_title=lower(movie_title)', #         \
                                'select * from films')) #                     \
   #\                        \                      `--- (internal to sqldf)    ^
   # \                        `--- refers to original 'films' --->--->--->--->--'
   #  `--<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<--.
   d <- sqldf(c('update d set actor_3_name=lower(actor_3_name)', #       \
                                'select * from d')) #                     \
   #                    \                      `--- (internal to sqldf)    ^
   #                     `--- refers to previously-created 'd' --->--->--->'
   #                         (repeat for other updates)
   ```

   **Option 3**, always reference/overwrite the original `films` variable:

   ```
   films <- read.csv("films.csv", ...)
   #   `--<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---+--<---<---<---<---<---.
   films <- sqldf(c('update films set movie_title=lower(movie_title)', #      \
                                 'select * from films')) #                     \
   #   \                        \                   `--- (internal to sqldf)    ^
   #    \                        ` --- refers to the first 'films' -->--->--->--'
   #     `-<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---<---+--<---<---<---<---<--.
   films <- sqldf(c('update films set actor_3_name=lower(actor_3_name)', #    \
                                 'select * from films')) #                     \
   #                            \                   `--- (internal to sqldf)    ^
   #                             ` --- refers to the second 'films' -->--->--->-'
   #                              (repeat for other updates)
   ```
3. `sqldf` inefficiencies. Each time you make a call to `sqldf`, it copies the entire dataset into a temporary table. Every. Time. You can reduce some of the overhead by combining all query strings into a single call, like so:

   ```
   films <- read.csv("films.csv", ...)
   films <- sqldf(c('update films set actor_3_name=lower(actor_3_name)',
                    'update films set actor_2_name=lower(actor_2_name)',
                    'update films set actor_1_name=lower(actor_1_name)',
                    'update films set director_name=lower(director_name)',
                    'select * from films'))
   ```
4. SQL inefficiencies. Your original code may be simplified for the question (which is fine), but if not then here goes. Since you do not appear to be conditioning your updates at all, you can combine the data-cleaning into one update. (This can be used with `dbExecute` as well.)

   ```
   films <- read.csv("films.csv", ...)
   films <- sqldf(c('update films set actor_3_name=lower(actor_3_name),
                                      actor_3_name=lower(actor_3_name),
                                      actor_2_name=lower(actor_2_name),
                                      actor_1_name=lower(actor_1_name),
                                      director_name=lower(director_name)',
                    'select * from films'))
   ```
5. Do you really need SQL? This can be done quite easily/quickly in R:

   ```
   films <- read.csv("films.csv", ...)
   films <- within(films, {
     actor_3_name <- tolower(actor_3_name)
     actor_2_name <- tolower(actor_2_name)
     actor_1_name <- tolower(actor_1_name)
     director_name <- tolower(director_name)
   })
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I use the code:
`sqldf('update films set director_name=lower(director_name)')` but again I recevie the same error.

Comment: I think you are not hearing me: ***it is a warning, not an error.*** The SQL command executes perfectly ... but since the table lasts only as long as `sqldf` is running, when your one `update` query is complete, the data are discarded. The *warning* has nothing to do with your desire to have an R variable updated when a database table is changed, for which I also suggested a workaround. Doing *just* `sqldf("update ...")` is pointless; to do so, you *must* do something like `sqldf(c("update ...", "select * from ..."))`.

Comment: I am sorry that I do not get completely your points. Actually I try the second format which you recommend `d<- sqldf(c("update ...", "select * from ..."))` 
but just for the first command, the table created but for next commands, I receive the same _**warning**_ and my dataset does not make any update and change.

Comment: My code works for me, including updating the local variable. I suggest you edit your question and include the exact code you are using. You also need to include in your question representative data (perhaps a *sample* of your real data), so that we can see that what you are expecting is logically correct in addition to be programmatically correct. (Perhaps just `dput(head(d))`, including enough rows to contain both some with and some without `"Colores"`.)

Comment: I have edited my question with exact code I have used.

Comment: If this answers your question, please "accept" the answer by selecting the checkmark to the left of it. (It's common etiquette on forums like this, and it provides "reputation points" for the time/effort spent on the answer.)

Comment: Thank you again for your time and kind guidance.

Comment: sqldf does have a facility for persistent connections. See example 10 on the home page. https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#example-10-persistent-connections

Comment: Also if you actually measure the speed you will find that sqldf compares favorably with base R in many cases   Although it was not written for the purpose of speed but more to allow one to easily use SQL without setting up create table statements unexpectedly it was found that some users were using it to get a speed advantage over base R.

Comment: @GGrothendieck I wondered if you would pipe in with any mis-speaks (on my part). I knew there was something with persistent connections but must have assumed it was for H2 or similar, thanks for setting me straight. My comment on overhead/speed is more applicable to larger datasets where the table-insert time is measurable, but I should do more benchmarking before throwing that out there, sorry.

Comment: Not so.  Some of the users using it for speed are using it for large data sets.  One user said he was able to get a job taking all night down to an hour.